# How to wait until timer stops

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have a reusable function `countDown(seconds: Int)` that contains Timer object. Function `takeRest()` calls `countDown(seconds: Int)` function and after calling immediately prints: "test text". What I'd like to do is to wait with executing print function until timer inside `countDown(seconds: Int)` function stop executing and keep `countDown()` function reusable. Any suggestions?

```
private func takeRest(){
            countDown(seconds: 10)
            print("test text")
        }

private func countDown(seconds: Int){
        secondsToCount = seconds
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ [weak self] timer in
            if (self?.secondsToCount)! > 0{
                self?.secondsToCount -= 1
                self?.timerDisplay.text = String((self?.secondsToCount)!)
            }
            else{
                self?.timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closure on countdown function, Please refer following code for reference.

```
private func takeRest(){
        countDown(seconds: 10) { 
            print("test text")
        }
    }

private func countDown(seconds: Int, then:@escaping ()->() ){
    let secondsToCount = seconds
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ [weak self] timer in
        if (self?.secondsToCount)! > 0{
            self?.secondsToCount -= 1
            self?.timerDisplay.text = String((self?.secondsToCount)!)

            //call closure when your want to print the text.
            //then()
        }
        else{
            //call closure when your want to print the text.
            then()
            self?.timer.invalidate()
            self?.timer = nil // You need to nil the timer to ensure timer has completely stopped. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want the `then` call in the else clause after `timer.invalidate` so that it executes when the timer is finished.

Comment: sure, but i am unaware of condition on which @barola_mes wants that text be printed .